# CorelDraw: How do I insert dynamic text for the document path?

Tags: text, corel-draw

This should be simple to do, but I'm having no luck figuring it out.

In Coreldraw, I want to out the document path on my titleblock, similar to what you'd see on the gutter of an engineering drawing.

An example would be `C:\users\jmac\121121_figure1.cdr`, and I'd like it to update itself when the document opens.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be of help:

If you click on the file in Explorer and then right click and get properties, highlight and copy the path and then paste into CDR as a text string. Not very elegant but it works.

[image]

[This question in the Corel forums](https://coreldraw.com/forums/p/36737/171902.aspx) also has a video (haven't checked it though) that explains how to use macros.